# Android Studio "No tests were found"

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, gradle

Has anyone been able to get tests to run in Android Studio (from the GUI and not terminal), I have been unable to run tests from the GUI.

Everytime I try to run tests through the GUI I just get the following message:

[image]

I am able to run the tests from terminal using the following command:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

I am running **Android Studio 0.5.2** with **Gradle 1.11 with Plugin 0.9.0** on **Mac OSX**

My project structure is as follows;

```
MyProject/
   src/
      androidTest/
         java/
             com.myproject.app.test/
                … (tests source code) …
      main/
         java/
             com.myproject.app/
                … (source code) …
         res/
                … (resources code) …
   build.gradle
```

My build.gradle file looks similar to the following:

```
…
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 12
        versionName "2.0"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19       
    testPackageName "com.test.foo"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
}
…
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I will be more than happy to here them.

Comment: Can you post the contents of one of your test files?

Comment: The content of the test files was not the issue, it was a problem with the misc.xml file in the .idea folder. But the test files were just simple TestCase files so I wouldn't see any reason why they be an issue.

Comment: @iamshanedoyle  You put /androidTest directory right under /src.  But it should be at the same level as /src, not under it.  Look at your build.gradle, and it should have: androidTest.setRoot('androidTest').

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found the cause of my problem.

In the **misc.xml** file which is located in the .idea folder of my project had an invalid attribute value for the **ProjectRootManager** component, which looked like the following:

```xml
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_6" assert-keyword="true" jdk-15="true" project-jdk-name="1.6 (3)" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
    <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/build/classes" />
</component>
```

So changing the `project-jdk-name` attribute value to just **"1.6"**, fixed the problem for me. Below is what it looked like after I had updated the value.

```xml
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_6" assert-keyword="true" jdk-15="true" project-jdk-name="1.6" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
    <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/build/classes" />
</component>
```

Hope this helps anyone out.

Comment: I had my `project-jdk-name` attribute set to string `JDK` changed it to `1.8`. Worked like charm!

Comment: Changed my 1.8 (2) to 1.8 but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 41):

Today I had the same problem with some Espresso tests and it was getting me crazy because everything seemed normal. Finally I discovered the problem was because the method annotated with `@BeforeClass` was throwing an exception. If something goes wrong in that method, the stacktrace of the exception is not shown in the *Log window* of the *Run tab* but in the *Log window* of the *Android Monitor tab*

If you want to reproduce the problem just add this to your testing class:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Sorry dude, you won't find any test!");
}
```

Comment: For me it was an issue with the dagger graph not being able to be created. The exception was showing up in the Log window of the Android Monitor tab and not in the Run tab!

Answer (score 16):

This can happen when the type of your run configuration is incorrect.

With me, this goes wrong when running an Espresso test which used to be a unit test. For some reason it still uses the Android JUnit test configuration when running this test. Manually creating an Android Instrumented Test solves the problem.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with AS 3.0, but it is reproducible only intermittently. I created an Android Instrumented Test manually, it ran for a while, then at one point I had a test failure and since then it won't detect instrumented tests at all. Says "no tests were found".

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. I am using both java and Kotlin in my module. I have created Junit test manually, but maybe I have done it incorrectly. Can you write how you create test manually?

Answer (score 10):

Just for posterity sakes, here's the solution that worked for me -

> The error you're seeing happens if AS for some reason thinks that the test that you're about to run is a unit and not an instrumentation test. Often this error goes away buy just clicking on the package instead of the actual class.

Found at https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing/issues/27#issuecomment-219074863

I just ran the tests by right clicking on the package name and choosing "Run 'Tests in {packageName}'" and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

To run instrumentation test cases on android mobile device with kotlin, add below
things into your app build.gradle:

```
 defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Add these permissions:

```
    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.2.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    }
```

I used below gradle version:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

```
 buildscript {
        
            ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71' 
          
            repositories {
                flatDir { dirs './lib' }
                google()
                mavenCentral()
                jcenter()
                maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
            }
        
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'     
                classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            }
        }
```

Then in the src->androidTest->java->com.example.demo-> create class DemoTest.kt.
If you need context, then get it via `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext`

If your test cases requires any permissions, then add below rule:

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var permissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)
```

You can do all set up inside:

```
 @Before
 fun setup() {
    // Do initial setup here
 }
```

and then write test cases like this:

```
@Test
fun testFunctionality() {
    // write your code here         
}
```

Comment: The only thing I had to change is `defaultConfig`, because I changed project setting to use `androidx` after creating the project.

Comment: YEEESSS thank you this was driving me crazy.  For me all I had to do was change `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` to `testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` in the `android{defaultConfig {...}...}` section of my app-level `build.gradle` file and the tests started magically being called.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me (invalidate caches...).

What worked was:

- click the configurations list drop down in the main toolbar.
- In it click "Edit configuration...".
- Delete the entry for my test.
- Back to the source, click the |>| button of the test I wanted to run.

It then inexplicably worked.

Comment: worked for me as well, It might have been due to me moving the test to `androidTest` package from `test`

Answer (score 2):

For me it was stupid thing. Simply switching from `Release` build variant to `Debug` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362916/disable-accept-test-storage-service-in-espresso) by [azizbekian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083957/azizbekian) in the [Android 10 API 29 documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes?hl=en#user-permission-legacy-apps) this issue can happen when running tests on an Emulator for the first time where the  app targets API29.

The emulator may be waiting for user input on a screen showing:

> Choose what to allow TestServices to access

There is more information about this in the docs here, but it seems there is a known issue with some versions of the android-test dependencies that can cause this prompt to appear.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes?hl=en#user-permission-legacy-apps

So be sure to check the screen on your emulator. In my case the issue was that my Emulator was awaiting confirmation that the TestServices component was granted the Storage permission, as per the screenshot in the linked SO issue and the Android documentation.

Comment: Thanks -- your answer put me on the right track. As explained in [that GitHub issue for android-test](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/450), the old (pre-AndroidX) android-test runner will NOT work on an emulator that has Android 10 API 29. Workaround is to use an emulator on Android 9 API 28.

Answer (score 1):

The issue resolved for me just by wiping data from my emulator. In logs, I could see there was not enough space.
It was not any config issue for me because the test I ran before running the test that gave me empty suite error worked fine and both test were at the same location in the project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was the emulator, when I tested with a real device, the error disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I will update this if I resolve the issue, but building my project with

```
debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version'
```

resulted in all of my tests reporting that

> No tests were found

including all tests which did not import the package. In the meantime, removing this from your gradle, and then calling "Clean Project" followed by "Invalidate Caches / Restart" resolved the issue.

**Edit:**

Your gradle must also include

```
debugImplementation "androidx.test:core:$core_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't declare the test class as public.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a was using a wrong testing dependency. I had the following in my build.gradle

```
testImplementation 'io.kotlintest.kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.4.2'
```

As you can see, this is for JUnit5. I changed it to the following

```
testImplementation 'io.kotlintest.kotlintest-runner-junit4:3.4.2'
```

And begone, error.

Answer (score 0):

**What happened in my case.**

**FYI** we have 2 types of unit tests

1. Local unit test (test/java folder for the android studio project)
2. Instrumentation unit test (androidTest/java folder for the android studio project)

I mistakenly create the Instrumentation test in the local unit test and then I directly copied moved that test from local unit to Instrumentation test. It start saying **"No test were found"**.

**Solution:** Just created a new test class for the Instrumentation test.

Always try to create a new test class in a specific test folder and start writing tests in it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

> File => Invalidate caches / Restart... => Invalidate and restart

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more thing to check that I stupidly missed when being on an old branch:

Make sure the test you are trying to run does not have an @Ignore annotation :)

Answer (score 0):

Silly thing, but just to be on the safe side, check that

- you have your test function where you intended and that
- all the opening and closing brackets of your main, setUp, tearDown etc. functions are fine in that file...

For example this

```
setUp(() {
   ...
   //is clearly not meant to be down here
   test('some test', () {}); 
});
```

can happen after a long day...

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this ("0 tests passed") when trying to run tests in Android Studio - it wasn't finding the test - even though I was running it by pressing that little green arrow right next to the test!

[image]

**Solution** - in my app-level `build.gradle`, changing

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ...
```

to

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ...
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63283091/851699) answer by Rupesh made it find the tests.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, **USING KOTLIN**, it didn't throw anything.
If I run in the terminal the command that it was trying to do:

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class xx.xxxxxxx.xx.xx.xxx.xxx.HomeActivityTests xx.xxxxxxx.xx.xx.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

it will throw an error:

> Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
>
> Cannot mock/spy class xx.xxxxxxx.xx.xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.ProductUseCase
>
> Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
>    - final class
>       at xx.xxxxxxx.xx.xx.rules.useCases.ProductUseCaseRule.(ProductUseCaseRule.kt:36)
>       at xx.xxxxxxx.xx.xx.xxx.xxx.HomeActivityTests.(HomeActivityTests.kt:25)
>       ... 20 more
>
> FAILURES!!!

and that shown me that I didn't `open` my class, as that's a **must** when testing with Kotlin

Comment: How did you open your class?

Comment: It's a must with Mockito, be specific.

Answer (score -2):

@Test annotation should be annotated from `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

Answer (score -4):

it is very simple question just press  **Alt + Shift + F10** and Run it in this way :)
PS:if it didn't work try **Shift + F10**.