# Disable/accept test storage service in Espresso

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso, android-testing, ui-testing

As can be seen in AndroidX Test 1.3.0 alpha04 [release notes](https://github.com/android/android-test/releases/tag/androidx-test-1.3.0-alpha04):

> Include the test storage service in the test services

Unfortunately, this makes standard `connectedDebugAndroidTest` to fail because this screen is getting displayed:

[image]

<sub>*Choose what to allow TestServices to access*</sub>

And this requires my interaction in order to proceed with UI testing.

This makes me to hang with already quite old `1.3.0-alpha03` artifacts, although `1.3.0-beta01` is already available.

**Question:**

How to accepts this permission via gradle command or within `testOptions` configuration? Somehow I can find neither any indication in docs nor a post in web with similar issue.

---

**UPDATE**

Yuki Hamada, an engineer from Espresso team, [confirmed](https://twitter.com/yuuki3655/status/1253097389474246656?s=20) that this is an issue and that they are working on that.

Answer (score -1):

You could brute force this by adding a Gradle task to run some ADB commands, but [GrantPermissionRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule) is the proper way.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is vague and gives no indication how to do that. This might be a comment, but certainly not an answer.